# Are there any Cocoa initializers that may be used to describe a person?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, naming-conventions

I'm curious to know if any of the Cocoa frameworks contain an initializer that might be mistaken for dealing with a human being. Obvious methods, (although I don't know if or where they exist) are `initWithAge`, or `initWithName`.

Are there any really clever sounding Cocoa initializers that may be applicable to people?

**Edit:**

I'm certainly not asking about the `new` operator. This is the kind of question you might get at a trivia event, but I'm absolutely serious about this. It can be answered objectively and definitively. Are there any cleverly named Cocoa initializers that can be understood to refer to people?

Comment: You mean to say is there any new operator kind of method in cocoa??

Comment: Absolutely not asking about the new method.

Comment: I have got to know what drove you to ask this question.

Comment: @Riley, haha! I'm updating my business cards that I made for WWDC 2012. It had `initWithAwesome` on it. I wanted something fresh.

Comment: Ah.  I feel like saying, "well now, I've seen it all," but of course your question proves I never will.  I hope they (the business cards) come out cool.

Comment: 2010 called, they want their business cards back.

Comment: @Abizern these were cool in 2012, where were you?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, I *think* you're asking this:

> Is there an established convention for initializing an object that describes a person?

So, the first thing I would do is grep through the framework headers looking for references to "person":

```
$ cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
$ grep -r 'Person\b' . | edit
```

(Yes, I default to looking in the Mac SDK.  Looking in the iOS SDK will be left as an exercise to the reader)

This results in 381 hits for me, mostly duplicated information.  But there are a couple of interesting hits:

- `ABPerson` from AddressBook.framework
- `EKParticipant` from EventKit
- `PSAuthor` from PubSub

**Unfortunately**, none of these results have an initializer, because they're all mainly for interacting with existing Person objects, not for creating new ones.  The exception is `-[ABPerson(ABPerson_vCard) initWithVCardRepresentation]`.  That's probably not helpful.

So we need to keep digging.  How else might we describe a person?  "People"? "Member"? "Individual"? "Customer"?  All of these would be pretty good things to look for.

And then I remembered that there's this obscure framework buried deep inside the OS X SDK that no one ever really talks about, called Collaboration.framework:

> The Collaboration framework is a set of Objective-C classes that allows developers to monitor identities and their attributes. ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/Collaboration_Coll/_index.html))

That looks promising!  And indeed, looking in here there's really interesting class: `CBIdentity`.  A `CBIdentity` "is used for accessing the attributes of an identity".  There are a bunch of different ways to create an identity, but I like this pattern, and I would recommend doing it like this:

An "MBIdentity" class would define ways to canonically identify a person.  So you could have `-initWithSocialSecurityNumber:` or `-initWithName:` or `-initWithBirthLocation:time:`, etc.  The purpose of this class would be to establish a collection of attributes that are sufficient to identify an individual.

Your "MBPerson" class would then have an `-initWithIdentity:` method that takes an `MBIdentity`.  The Person would then take on the characteristics of its composed Identity.

I suppose the important thing to realize here is that there are many ways to establish *identity* (and hence many properties/initializers on an `MBIdentity`).  But once you've established an identity, only one *Person* has that identity (and so your `Person` class only has an `initWithIdentity:` method).

Comment: In the immortal words of Christopher Eccleston as the Doctor: Fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

Strange question... erm...

```
initWithKind: // nice, nasty...
initWithUser: // username
initWithColor: // black, white
initWithStyle: // cool, geeky
initWithTitle: // Dr
initWithSize: // big, small
```

composed versions

```
initWithTitle:@"Dr" message:@"You are crazy"
initWithTitle:@"Your Honour" style:@"serious" handler:@"wife"
```

although these are from `BlockKit` so they might not count...